# Getting different class

Tags: ruby

```
class A
  def self.jeg
    p"hi"
  end

  def self.nat
    p 54
  end
end

A.jeg.class

A.nat.class
```

In this program I used `p`.

When I run this program, I got the below results

```
1.9.3-p194 :009 > A.jeg.class
"hi"
 => String 

1.9.3-p194 :010 > A.nat.class
54
=> Fixnum 


class B
  def self.boo
    puts "hi"
  end

  def self.gan
    puts 25
  end
end

B.boo.class

B.gan.class
```

In this program I used `puts` instead of `p`

When I run this program, I got below results

```
1.9.3-p194 :021 > B.boo.class
hi
 => NilClass 

1.9.3-p194 :022 > B.gan.class
25
 => NilClass
```

Why did i get `NilClass` when I use `puts` instead of `p`?

Comment: Question is not clear. Do you want to know the reason why it is designed so?

Comment: yes. i want to know the reason @sawa

Answer (score 8):

Because the specification says so:

[Kernel.p](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-p)

> p(obj) → obj

[Kernel.puts](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-puts)

> puts(obj, ...) → nil

Comment: According to the OP's comment, this does not answer the question. Note that a why-question is ambiguous (Cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tinbergen%27s_four_questions).

Answer (score 1):

The OP's question is not clear, but according to the comment that the OP gave, the OP is asking for the reason it was designed so.

---

It is because the (primary) purpose of `puts` is to print something to the terminal in production code. Other than that, it does not have particular purpose, so the default return value `nil` is assigned as the return value. For `p`, its purpose it to temporarily display the value of some expression during development, and in most typical use, it is inserted in the middle of the code. Hence, it is important that it does not affect the other part of the code. That is why it returns the receiver itself.

Answer (score 0):

The **return value** of **p** and **puts** is differnt.

the class method is called on the return value of the method

In the case of p , it prints and **returns ths object**
class  is called on the object (**object.class**)

in the case of puts, it prints object and **returns nil**
class  is called on nil. (**nil.class**)